# Is asking for learning resources on topic here?

Tags: discussion, faq-contents

I've become accustomed to asking this question on every new SE site I come to, just so I know the boundaries. Especially on a beta site.

I was wondering, is asking for some recommended reading for the beginning UI/UX developer on topic on this site?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question. Other SE sites will close your question fast if you ask for such things. What is the policy here?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you search for existing questions before you post the questions on UX. Then you'll find [Must-read User Interface books](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book) and [Which prototyping tools](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools) for example.
There are also the [training](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) and [education](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tags, among [others](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: I tried searching before posting this. I didn't know what to serch, so I didn't find anything.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I just meant searching before you ask the questions you mean to ask on UX, not that you shouldn't have asked this one :). Sorry if it wasn't clear.