# Asking for learning resources is on topic here?

Tags: discussion

On other Stack Exchange sites, requests for learning resources and books would be closed within minutes as off topic. Is this allowed here? Why?

I ask because [this happened](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/126496/webdesign-ux-ui-podcasts-and-other-resources)

[This question has been asked before](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/is-asking-for-learning-resources-on-topic-here/579#579) but the answer is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, I think not.

Though information like this would certainly be useful for many users, a collection of answers that each say "*I found this link useful when learning about designing menus. Hope you like it!*" doesn't fit well in this format.

From the [what-not-to-ask page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site...

Perhaps if our chat wasn't ***entirely dead***, I'd recommend directing people there to ask these questions...